# $I\mid J \iff I \supseteq J$ using localisation?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain. We know that for ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ we have $I\mid J \iff I \supseteq J$. This fact is used for example in Marcus' *Number Fields* to show that we have unique factorization of ideals in $R$. However its proof for me is element based and doesn't seem very slick.

**My question is:**

> Can we show $I\mid J \iff I \supseteq J$ using localization (not knowing about unique factorization of ideals in $R$)?

If this is possible, I would only like hints on how to do it as I would like to complete the problem myself.

Comment: How do you define $I\mid J$  ?

Comment: @QiL We say that $I | J$ if there exists an ideal $L$ so that $J = IL$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $K=J:I$. Then $K_{\mathfrak p}=J_{\mathfrak p}:I_{\mathfrak p}$. Since $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a DVR we get $I_{\mathfrak p}K_{\mathfrak p}=J_{\mathfrak p}$ and we are done.